Show that the ideal $\operatorname{rad} (a^2+bc, d^2+bc, (a+d)b, (a+d)c) = (ad-bc,a+d)$ but $(a^2+bc, d^2+bc, (a+d)b, (a+d)c) \not= (ad-bc,a+d)$

We identify the space $M_{2,2}(k)$ of $2\times2$-matrices over $k$ with $\Bbb A^4(k)$ (with coordinates $a,b,c,d$). We define ideals $$\mathfrak{a} := (a^2+bc,d^2+bc,(a+d)b,(a+d)c) \subseteq k[a,b,c,d]$$ $$\mathfrak{b} := (ad-bc,a+d) \subseteq k[a,b,c,d]$$ and denote their vanishing loci by $V(\mathfrak{a})$ resp. $V(\mathfrak{b})$. Prove that $$X := V(\mathfrak{a}) = V(\mathfrak{b}) = \{ A\in M_{2,2}(k) \mid A \text{ is nilpotent }\}$$ i.e., that a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d\end{pmatrix}$ is nilpotent if and only if the determinant and trace are zero. Moreover, prove that $\operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{b}$ but $\mathfrak{a}\neq\mathfrak{b}$. The affine algebraic set $X$ is called the nilpotent cone.

I am trying to do the above algebraic geometry exercise. I managed to show that $A$ is nilpotent iff $A^2=0$ iff $\det A = \operatorname{tr} A =0$, but I couldn't show that $\operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{a} =\mathfrak{b} $ and $\mathfrak{a} \not= \mathfrak{b}$.
Here is what I have tried:
For $\operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{a} =\mathfrak{b}$, we have $\operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{a} = I(V(\mathfrak{a})) = I(V(\mathfrak{b})) = \operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{b}$ by Hilbert Nullstellensatz, so it suffices to show that $\operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{b}$. Since $\mathfrak{b} \subseteq \operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{b}$, it suffices to show $\operatorname{rad} \mathfrak{b} \subseteq \mathfrak{b}$, and I have troubles in showing it.
For $\mathfrak{a} \not= \mathfrak{b}$, I can't think of any way that didn't involve a lot of complicated computation.
Thanks for helping.

I've retyped your image using MathJax. Please do this in the future when possible, and please consider adding a source to the problem with an [edit[.

Take the standard grading on $k[a,b,c,d]$ where $a,b,c,d$ are in degree one. Then $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are homogeneous ideals, and $\mathfrak{a}$ is generated in degree two while $\mathfrak{b}$ has an element in degree one, so we have $\mathfrak{a}\neq\mathfrak{b}$.
To see that $\mathfrak{b}$ is radical, compute the quotient: $k[a,b,c,d]/(ad-bc,a+d)\cong k[a,b,c]/(-a^2-bc)$ by the map sending $d\mapsto -a$. But $k[a,b,c]/(a^2+bc)$ is a domain, isomorphic to the subalgebra of $k[x,y]$ generated by $x^2,xy,-y^2$ (fulfilling the roles of $b,a,c$, respectively).
